# If I remove fields from a document, can that freed space be reused?

Tags: mongodb

I've seen questions about compacting the MongoDB database file, and about reusing space freed by removing whole documents, but I can't find any information about whether removing fields from documents will free up space for other new documents.

Specifically, I have documents representing the results of some operation, containing metadata about it, and the eventual result of the operation, as well as a large, detailed log. The log is orders of magnitude larger than all the other fields. I would like to keep the other fields, but after some time the logs take up more space than they're worth, so I'd like to remove them - but only if there is a point to doing so!

Will this do what I want? Or do I need to create new documents as copies of the old ones but without the large field, and remove the old documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How document space is allocated

The underlying concept is that MongoDB allocates *record* space for your *document* which allows that document to grow in place. The difference between the size of the document and the record is called *padding*. Ample padding reduces the performance impact of document moves.

As surmised by @NeilLunn, deleting fields from a document will not return that record space to the free list. This is also noted in the documentation on [Record Padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/):

> If an update operation causes the document to decrease in size, for instance if you perform an $unset or a $pop update, the document remains in place and effectively has more padding. If the document remains this size, the space is not reclaimed until you perform a compact or a repairDatabase operation.

#### Allocation Strategies

There are (as at MongoDB 2.2) two server-side collection allocation strategies available:

1. Allocate record space based on a [Padding Factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/#padding-factor). MongoDB automatically calculates a collection [`paddingFactor`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/#collStats.paddingFactor) based on historical document growth. The document size is multiplied by the padding factor to determine the desired record allocation, so the record sizes will vary. This is the default allocation strategy for MongoDB production versions through 2.4.
2. Allocate record space based on [Power Of 2 Sizes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes). In this case MongoDB allocates record space in powers of 2 (eg. 4, 8, 16, .. up to 4Mb and then in 1Mb increments). There will be a limited number of record sizes with this allocation strategy, which leads to more effective re-use of free space for collections with frequent deletions or document growth. This is an optional allocation strategy in MongoDB 2.2 and 2.4, and will be the default allocation in MongoDB 2.6.

In addition to the server-side collection allocation strategies, it is also possible to add [manual padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#can-i-manually-pad-documents-to-prevent-moves-during-updates) to supplement either of the built-in allocation approaches. For example, if your documents start very small and grow quickly before reaching a typical size you may wish to allow for that growth.

It is worth noting that the allocation strategy is only considered at the time a document is inserted or moved (i.e. when record space is allocated). Enabling the `usePowerOf2Sizes` does not affect any historical record allocations in a collection, only the new ones. You can also specify a starting `paddingFactor` or `paddingBytes` to use when [compacting a collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/#dbcmd.compact).

### Managing your space usage

> Specifically, I have documents representing the results of some operation, containing metadata about it, and the eventual result of the operation, as well as a large, detailed log. The log is orders of magnitude larger than all the other fields. I would like to keep the other fields, but after some time the logs take up more space than they're worth, so I'd like to remove them - but only if there is a point to doing so!
>
> Will this do what I want? Or do I need to create new documents as copies of the old ones but without the large field, and remove the old documents?

You have several choices here:

- adjust your data model so the metadata and the log data are in separate collections; in this case you can drop old log documents and the space can be reused
- copy & re-save the documents without the unwanted log fields
- run a periodic [`repairDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) to reclaim the excessive record space allocated to the removed log fields

In all of the above cases I would recommend enabling the `usePowerOf2Sizes` option for the collection with the log data, as this allocation strategy will help with reuse of free space.

If possible, adjusting your data model would be the most efficient approach. With powerOf2Sizes, copying and re-saving the documents may mitigate the need to run repair, but as a last resort you could run a periodic repair.

Comment: An excellent answer; thank you! I think the simplest option in my current system will be to re-add the document with the field removed. I'll make sure to use the `usePowerOf2Sizes` option; I didn't know there were options for controlling padding size until now. A schema change would be the better option if I had the time!

Answer (score 1):

Going to prefix this with "not really an answer", as that is probably left to someone with more knowledge of the implementation, and therefore most likely someone from MongoDB itself.

The general premise I'm working on here is "No". Largely because of what you are aware of concerning document deletion and that space being moved to the "free list" where as I understand another document could be placed in that space, as long as it is "small" enough to use the space that has been freed.

The general premise is that the "document" is the thing that will need to use contiguous storage, and considering concepts such as "manual padding" in order to deliberately allocate space for a document so it does not "move around" seems to predicate that once you reduce that document size it's not going to get moved to where it takes up less space.

So that's a very non-technical observation, but an observation on what parts I know. Considering your use case though there may be an alternative.

As you mention you have "particularly large" logging info, that after a period of time may not be of further real use. Since that is the part you think you can discard, it may be worth considering putting that into a separate collection.

Of course there are the considerations of changing your approach from the "embedded" model that you have, but given the case you say, this would result in actual document removal. And as such is more in tune with how MongoDB is going to re-claim space.

Alternately, as you suggest a manual creation of a compacted copy would equally have the same result. But let's possibly wait for the experts to chime in.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Useful despite not being an answer :)

Comment: @BenHymers Thought someone would come in eventually. Stennie is from MongoDB so would know all the gory details.